# What is the difference between DB::beginTransaction() and DB::transaction()?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, transactions, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2.

I would like to know what are the differences between :

1. `DB::beginTransaction()` and `DB::transaction()`
2. `DB::commitTransction()` and `DB::commit()`
3. `DB::rollbackTransction()` and `DB::rollback()`

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: `DB::commitTransaction()` and `DB::rollbackTransaction()` do not exist.

Comment: @Doom5 But I saw that here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/do-you-use-database-transactions-for-your-eloquent-queries

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`DB::beginTransaction()` will only begin a transaction, while for `DB::transaction()` you must pass a Closure function that will be executed *inside* a transaction.

So this:

```
DB::transaction(function() {
    // Do something and save to the db...
});
```

is the same as this:

```
// Open a try/catch block
try {
    // Begin a transaction
    DB::beginTransaction();

    // Do something and save to the db...

    // Commit the transaction
    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // An error occured; cancel the transaction...
    DB::rollback();
    
    // and throw the error again.
    throw $e;
}
```

As you can see, `DB::transaction()` is a "helper" function to avoid writing code to catch errors, begin a transaction, commit the transaction, and optionally rollback (cancel the transaction) if an error occured.

If you have a more complex logic, or need an specific behaviour, you will manually build your transaction; if your logic is rather simple, `DB::transaction()` is the way to go.

As for `DB::commitTransaction()` and `DB::rollbackTransaction()`, I can't find information.

It's a good practice to check the source code of the things you use, because you will learn how they are written, as well as how to write. [Here's the file](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L535) with the source for these methods.

Comment: Thank You. But I saw `DB::commitTransaction0` here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/do-you-use-database-transactions-for-your-eloquent-queries

Comment: @Hamed Might have been a mistake.

Comment: @HamedKamrava `DB::commitTransaction()` **

Comment: I think now `DB::commitTransaction()` has been renamed to `DB::commit()`.

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel 6 to use Transactions must be use the following helper functions.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

try {
    // For Begin a transaction
    DB::beginTransaction();

    // Do something

    // Commit the transaction
    DB:: commit();
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    // An error occured
    DB::rollback();
    
    // and throw the error again.
    throw $e;
}
```

if you use the DB::commitTransaction(); function, get error undefined function.